# how to draw information from lists inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
released = {
        "Noah" : ["1",100]
    }
print("Your Bank Balance is", released["Noah",[1]])
```

I am getting an error code of :

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

What I want to happen is that it will print one hundred as the bank balance.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Change your print call to:

`print("Your Bank Balance is", released["Noah"][1])`

This way you will get the value stored in the key `"Noah"`, and access to the second element of the list. Keep in mind that you should "unpack" the datastructures one by one.